# Converting unicode codes to UTF-8

Tags: php, unicode, encoding

I have the following string written in a file:

```
\u0410\u043d\u0442\u043e\u043d \u0411\u043e\u0440\u0438\u0441\u0435\u043d\u043a\u043e
```

And I want to replace it with UTF-8 readable characters. How can I do this?

The file itself is in UTF-8. The string in unicode codes is cyrillic.

I have tried utf_encode(), json_decode(), mb functions...nothing works.

EDIT:

This is what I have tried:

```
echo html_entity_decode(preg_replace("/U\+([0-9A-F]{4})/", "&#x\\1;", '\u0410\u043d\u0442\u043e\u043d \u0411\u043e\u0440\u0438\u0441\u0435\u043d\u043a\u043e'), ENT_NOQUOTES, 'UTF-8') . '<br>';
echo utf8_encode('\u0410\u043d\u0442\u043e\u043d \u0411\u043e\u0440\u0438\u0441\u0435\u043d\u043a\u043e') . '<br>';
echo json_decode('"' . '\u0410\u043d\u0442\u043e\u043d \u0411\u043e\u0440\u0438\u0441\u0435\u043d\u043a\u043e' . '"'); 
        die();
```

And the output is:

```
\u0410\u043d\u0442\u043e\u043d \u0411\u043e\u0440\u0438\u0441\u0435\u043d\u043a\u043e
\u0410\u043d\u0442\u043e\u043d \u0411\u043e\u0440\u0438\u0441\u0435\u043d\u043a\u043e
ĐĐ˝ŃĐžĐ˝ ĐĐžŃĐ¸ŃĐľĐ˝ĐşĐž
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Гугл вам в помощь :) In Google we trust

```
function decodeUnicode($s, $output = 'utf-8') 
{ 
    return preg_replace_callback('#\\\\u([a-fA-F0-9]{4})#', function ($m) use ($output) { 
        return iconv('ucs-2be', $output, pack('H*', $m[1])); 
    }, $s); 
} 

echo decodeUnicode('\u0410\u043d\u0442\u043e\u043d \u0411\u043e\u0440\u0438\u0441\u0435\u043d\u043a\u043e', 'windows-1251');
```

result:

```
Антон Борисенко
```

Comment: I really don't get those encodings :D The result is actually `Ŕíňîí Áîđčńĺíęî`

Comment: It gives answer in windows-1251 coding

Comment: Its 2na arg of function. omit it to have utf-8

Comment: Changing argument to utf-8 outputs `ĐĐ˝ŃĐžĐ˝ ĐĐžŃĐ¸ŃĐľĐ˝ĐşĐž`

Comment: it works on my local server and nowhere more :) I'll try tonight

Answer (score 1):

Using `json_decode` function:

```
<?php

$str = '\u0410\u043d\u0442\u043e\u043d \u0411\u043e\u0440\u0438\u0441\u0435\u043d\u043a\u043e';
$str = json_decode('"' . $str . '"');

header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
echo $str;
```

Output: `Антон Борисенко`

Comment: Thanks! Any other methods, without the header? I need to write it to file afterwards.

Comment: @khernik: splash58 found another method, the string you got is valid, but the way the browser understands it is wrong : it doesn't assume it's UTF-8 by default, that's why I added the header to make the browser to understand that this is a UTF-8 string. You can save it to a file without worrying about that header.